# Convert eg. 2012-05-25 to seconds since January 1 1970

Tags: sql-server, date, time, timespan, epoch

I have a database where I save time as `time()` from php, which is seconds since `1 jan 1970`.

Is there any way I can convert, for example `2012-12-12` to seconds since `1 jan 1970`?

I want to do like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE date > '2012-11-30' AND date < '2012-12-30'
```

Is this even possible?

(I would like to do it without any php date())

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+date+to+unix+timestamp&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) is going to be your friend here:

```
select datediff(s, '1970-01-01', '2012-12-12') as SecondsSinceEpoch
```

Note that because datediff returns an int, the maximum datetime you can compare (using seconds) with Jan 1st, 1970 is `2038-01-19 03:14:07`.