# Calculate concurrent calls with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate concurrent calls in MySQL. The columns in my table are **Starttime**, **Endtime**, and **ID**. Using the time fields as is, I was able to wirte a query that returns the number of concurrent calls by Starttime. When I try to cast the time fields into the nearest minute, then I get incorrect counts. I have developed a solution to get the correct counts when rounded to the nearest minute, but if feels neither clear nor efficient.

Here's my table:

```
create table `test_table4` (
`Starttime` DATETIME default null,
`Endtime` DATETIME  default null,
`ID` varchar(20)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:03:02', '2006-12-30 08:03:04', 'A');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:33:02', '2006-12-30 08:37:45', 'B');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:33:02', '2006-12-30 08:33:05', 'C');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:33:06', '2006-12-30 08:37:44', 'C');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:40:21', '2006-12-30 08:41:25', 'D');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:40:21', '2006-12-30 08:41:25', 'E');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:47:00', '2006-12-30 08:47:47', 'F');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:56:01', '2006-12-30 08:56:01', 'G');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:56:01', '2006-12-30 08:56:04', 'H');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:56:07', '2006-12-30 08:57:37', 'I');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:56:07', '2006-12-30 08:57:35', 'J');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:56:28', '2006-12-30 08:56:41', 'K');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:56:28', '2006-12-30 08:56:41', 'L');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:57:08', '2006-12-30 08:57:24', 'M');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:57:09', '2006-12-30 08:57:24', 'N');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:58:02', '2006-12-30 08:58:02', 'O');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:58:59', '2006-12-30 08:59:59', 'R');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 08:58:59', '2006-12-30 08:59:58', 'Q');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 09:00:34', '2006-12-30 09:00:35', 'S');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 09:00:55', '2006-12-30 09:02:55', 'T');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 09:01:27', '2006-12-30 09:01:28', 'U');
insert into `test_table4` (`Starttime`, `Endtime`, `ID`) VALUES ('2006-12-30 09:02:18', '2006-12-30 09:02:18', 'V');
```

To get the number of concurrent calls using Starttime as is, I run the following query.

```
select c1.Starttime, count(distinct c2.ID)
from test_table4 c1
left join test_table4 c2
on c1.Starttime between c2.Starttime and
c2.Endtime AND c2.Endtime IS NOT NULL
group by c1.Starttime;
```

This give me the right answer. Note the ID C makes two calls. This causes my analysis to go wrong when I cast the starttime and endtimes to the nearest minute and get the counts.

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(CEILING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c1.starttime)/60)*60) as Date_Truncated, count(distinct c2.ID) as all_calls
from test_table4 c1 
left join test_table4 c2 
on FROM_UNIXTIME(CEILING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c1.starttime)/60)*60)
between FROM_UNIXTIME(CEILING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c2.starttime)/60)*60) and 
FROM_UNIXTIME(CEILING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c2.Endtime)/60)*60)    
and c2.Endtime is not null
GROUP BY Date_Truncated;
```

The query returns that at 8:34 there are two calls, but actually there are three, as C makes two calls - one at at 8:33:02 and 8:33:06, so together with ID B, there at three calls at 8:34 after casting 8:33:xx for B and C to the nearest minute.

I have to run `distinct count c2.ID` otherwise, as running `count c2.ID` returns inaccurate counts. I came up a solution, but it feels inelegant and  inefficient.

```
select final_data.Date_Truncated, final_data.all_calls/final_data.row_count as concurrent_calls_count
from
(select *
from
(select FROM_UNIXTIME(CEILING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c1.starttime)/60)*60) as Date_Truncated, count(c2.ID) as all_calls
from test_table4 c1 
left join test_table4 c2 
on FROM_UNIXTIME(CEILING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c1.starttime)/60)*60)
between FROM_UNIXTIME(CEILING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c2.starttime)/60)*60) and 
FROM_UNIXTIME(CEILING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c2.Endtime)/60)*60)
and c2.Endtime is not null
GROUP BY Date_Truncated) t1
left join
(select FROM_UNIXTIME(CEILING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Starttime)/60)*60) as    Date_Truncated2, count(*) as row_count
from test_table4
group by  Date_Truncated2) t2
on t1.Date_Truncated = t2.Date_Truncated2) final_data;
```

Is there a simpler or better way of calculating concurrent calls that I am missing?

Comment: It might help if you state exactly what you mean by "concurrent". Some would argue that at least 60 calls could be possible in a minute without any of them being concurrent; but if there were two instances of two overlapping at two different times within the minute, should that be 2 or 4 concurrent (even if there were 58 other non-overlapping ones in that minute)?

Comment: The code you posted is a great start to a question, my only advice would be to try to make the code look less like a wall of text. I would recommend adding spacing and indentation in to your code to help with readability. If there is any code that isn't needed to replicate your issue, I would remove that as well.

Comment: @Uueerdo - if there are two instance of two overlapping calls at different times within the minute, then that would be 4 overlapping calls. I want to count each use of a phone line - so the count is 4. It doesn't matter if the same person made two different calls within a minute, or if the same person is making two different calls simultaneously, I want to count each instance of a phone line being used.

Comment: I'd think the issue you had was "rounding" the times to the *nearest* minute. 15:30:55 and 15:30:05 occur in the same minute so should round the same way. Instead of jumping through all UNIX_TIMESTAMP conversion and deconversion, you could try something like `TO_SECONDS(starttime) DIV 60`.

Comment: @Uueerdo Thaks. Do you know what's the equivalent to_seconds in sql server?

Comment: @spaul Your question's tag, and the create and insert queries you've shown all suggest MySQL. (According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12923746/4104224), something like `DATEDIFF(s, [somestartdatetime], [datetimetoconvert])` is what you are looking for.)